# didFinishUserInfoTransfer finished successfully - but still with outstandingUserInfoTransfers Objects

Tags: watchkit, watchconnectivity, wcsession

First I use the "transferUserInfo"-method in order to send a dictionary from the iPhone to the Apple Watch:

```
let dicty = //...my dictionary of property-list values...
if WCSession.isSupported() {
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
    if session.paired == true {  // Check if your Watch is paired with your iPhone
        if session.watchAppInstalled == true {  // Check if your Watch-App is installed on your Watch
            session.transferUserInfo(dicty)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am using the following delegate callback method "didFinishUserInfoTransfer" to check upon the state of the transfer:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didFinishUserInfoTransfer userInfoTransfer: WCSessionUserInfoTransfer, error: NSError?) {
    if error == nil {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        let transfers = session.outstandingUserInfoTransfers
        if transfers.count > 0 {  //--> is always > 0, why ?????????
            for trans in transfers {
                trans.cancel()  // cancel transfer that will be sent by updateApplicationContext
                let dict = trans.userInfo
                session.transferUserInfo(dict)  //--> creates enless-transfer cycle !!!!!
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In the Apple documentation, it sais about the didFinishUserInfoTransfer method:

```
The session object calls this method when a data transfer initiated by the
current app finished, either successfully or unsuccessfully. Use this method
to note that the transfer completed or to respond to errors, perhaps by
trying to send the data again at a later time.
```

So far so good - I understood. But now - there is something I do not understand:

If didFinishUserInfoTransfer is entered and the error == nil, why on earth can the session.outstandingUserInfoTransfers COUNT be bigger than zero ??????

According to the Apple-documentation, the only non-error-state of didFinishUserInfoTransfer should be when the transfer is over !! Bit it does not seem to be over... Why ???

Thanks for any clarification on this.

And also, I am glad of any example-code on how to use these 3 methods correctly !
(i.e.

- session.transferUserInfo(dicty)
- didFinishUserInfoTransfer
- session.outstandingUserInfoTransfers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the userInfoTransfer that triggers the `didFinishUserInfoTransfer` callback is not removed from the `outstandingUserInfoTransfers` until the delegate callback has returned. To get the behavior you want (where count can go down to 0) you'd want to dispatch_async away from the delegate callback thread. So this should work:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didFinishUserInfoTransfer userInfoTransfer: WCSessionUserInfoTransfer, error: NSError?) {
    if error == nil {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            let transfers = session.outstandingUserInfoTransfers
            if transfers.count > 0 {  //--> will in most cases now be 0
                for trans in transfers {
                    trans.cancel()  // cancel transfer that will be sent by updateApplicationContext
                    let dict = trans.userInfo
                    session.transferUserInfo(dict)  // ***
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

That said, I don't quite understand why you'd want to cancel all the remaining outstanding userInfoTransfers whenever any of them completes, just to re-queue them (spot in question is indicated by `***`)

Comment: Good question at the end. I indeed, do not want to re-queue them. The last statement (i.e. session.transferUserInfo(dict)) will therefore soon be ommitted ! It was only there in order to debug.... Thanks for your solution - I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I tried your above code. But unfortunately, in simulator - still the same behaviour... (i.e. count > 0 and therefore one might think there was no transfer - but the transfer was received at the Watch-side). Any idea why this "didFinishUserInfoTransfer still shows a count>0 (and error==nil) even tough the transfer has passed to the Watch ???

Comment: Finally, found a solution: It seems a simulator-problem. At least, after Clearing-XCode / deleting all drivedData (i.e. deleting /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData) and after Resetting both Simulators (iPhone & Watch) --> it finally worked with your code above !!! Many thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

There is a little misunderstanding, as far as I read the docs: **only send again if an error occurs**. To have outstanding userInfoTransfers if no error has been raised is the expected behavior; they have not yet successfully been send and are still queued.

*Btw. code uses the actual dispatchQueue.*

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didFinish userInfoTransfer: WCSessionUserInfoTransfer, error: Error?) {

if error != nil {  // resend if an error occured

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let transfers = session.outstandingUserInfoTransfers
            if transfers.count > 0 {

                // print("open transfers: \(transfers.count)")

                for trans in transfers {

                    // print("resend transfer")

                    trans.cancel()  // cancel transfer
                    let dict = trans.userInfo
                    session.transferUserInfo(dict)  // send again
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So, if I understood correctly, the error==nil of this callback-method only indicates that the queueing-up was successful but does not tell anything about the actual userInfoTransfer itself (since it hasn't even started). Right ? But then, how do you check on successful transfer ? (I am not interested in successful queueing information ;))

Comment: I presume error == nil means successful send.
Therefore you can get the information which object has been send afterwards, since the WCSessionUserInfoTransfer class has the userInfo property - the data itself.

Comment: Hmmm - you are saying above that 'error == nil' does not mean successfully sent yet (but only successful queueing). Well, I get your point. Maybe 'error == nil' means all of the following: A) Successful queueing / B) speaking nothing against being sent soon successfully.... Hmm... and therefore take the data provided just as successfully transferred right away since the Apple API does not tell you more ;)